# Core Data Property Not Found on Type Equipment

Tags: core-data

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain this error?
It works fine if I use [equipment valueForKey:@"name"]; or another property yet I can't use the Core Data generated accessors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that even though I declare @class Equipment in the header file for the class using the Equipment object I also have to #import "Equipment.h" in the implementation file.